# Saxon genitive. Can I use it for objects?

Tags: grammar, saxon-genitive

I am translating from italian, and a question suddenly struck me:

Can I say:

> The items’ content in the Navigation Drawer.

or

> This is a class handling the cards’ layout.

Comment: Yes, you can; examples are even given in the [tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/saxon-genitive/info). You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @choster Actually the tag wiki doesn't have examples of an inanimate "possessor", which is what this question is about. Perhaps it should include one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Fair enough; I must have skimmed it too quickly. I have expanded it, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

We often use the nouns attributively there:  "... *item* content in the Navigation Drawer" and "... a class handing *card* layout".

Comment: While *card layout* is fine, my default interpretation of *item content* and *item's content* would be completely different things.  *"the item content in the Navigation Drawer"*: the things that are in the navigation drawer and are called *items*; *"the item's content in the Navigation Drawer"*: the content associated with a particular item.

Comment: The OP's examples are plural possessives.